# Using plain javaScript instead of coffeeScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Does my ruby on rails app have to use coffeeScript or could I can I Just use plain javaScript?

Comment: remove .coffee from the end of your file and it runs plain js. so application.js.coffee -> application.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can just use Javascript. You have your files in app/assets/javascripts/*.js . On local dev, do a view source and you will see your files there.

On production, the Asset Pipeline will concatenate and minify.

Answer (score 7):

You need to ensure not having the same filename both in javascript and coffeescript.

For example: having both the files

```
assets/javascripts/application.coffee  
assets/javascripts/application.js
```

**will only get the coffeescript loaded.**

Answer (score 1):

You can also write plain JS in CoffeeScript files, just put ` around it:

```
hi = `function() {
  return [document.title, "Hello JavaScript"].join(": ");
}`
```

Comment: In other words, you can have BOTH JS and CoffeeScript in the same .coffee file, if you enclose your JS code in backticks. Thanks, Qasim.

Answer (score 0):

you can write whatever you want jquery or javascript just make sure the extension for that is js